# In Apple Mail, how to disable weird search

Tags: macos, mail.app

When in Apple Mail, not while composing a message but while simply looking at your inbox, then touching a letter key or a number key will jump to another email. I don't know exactly how the next email is selected, it looks like the first message containing that particular letter/number.

Can I disable this odd functionality?

Comment: It's not really 'odd', it's a system-wide selection function. It works just about everywhere you've multiple items that could be selected. Finder is the most obvious. MS Windows does it a similar way.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not system-wide, for example when I am in a webbrowser, typing the key 'S' doesn't switch me to the tab that happens to contain the letter 'S'. In some places like Finder it's very relevant behavior, but not (IMO) in an email client.

Comment: Browsers are a poor example. Tabs work the same system-wide too, but not like file  or menu lists. Menus, Open/Save dialogs, Activity Monitor, Disk Utility etc all exhibit the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on context, and as suggested in comments, is a system wide behaviour for lists. Your comment re browser tabs isn't relevant as tabs aren't lists.

If your current focus is in a list of emails for example, then the behaviour you describe helps to select the next email where the subject of the email begins with the letter you type, depending on sort order.

Similarly the same behaviour in Finder helps to select the next file with that letter, or if you type fast enough, the first and second.

To prevent the behaviour, just click elsewhere in the Mail app, say, on the body of the email.

Comment: Thanks for the lists explanation. The issue is that it even 'finds' something when there's nothing to find. If I press '1', it doesn't jump to a message whose subject starts with 1, it jumps to a message containing 1 somewhere in the message body, i.e. a full-text search with just one character, which seems quite useless to me, as well as quite confusing. Indeed, clicking on the email body 'solves' it, however that requires an extra click.